# i need a regex replacing 5th to last digit of an 11-digit number c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i need a regex replacing 5th to last digit of an 11-digit number by asterisk

Answer (score 2):

This is an easier way:

```
var newStr = oldString.substring(0,4) + new String('*' , 6);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably faster (and simpler) to get the first 5 characters and add asterisks manually.

JS solution: https://jsfiddle.net/e54x7dh7/

`var output = input.substr(0,5);
for (var i = output.length; i < input.length; i++) {
    output += '*';
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this [Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ccxZac) as an alternate solution:

```
string oldString = "12345678910";
var newStr = String.Join("",oldString.Select((x,i)=> i<4 ? x:'*'));
Console.WriteLine(newStr);
```